# Passing weights to cross entropy loss

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to assign different weights to different classes, so I have modified my loss criterion as such:

I had to convert the weight tensor to double `torch.DoubleTensor(weight)` since my `model` is already moved to `double()`. Am I doing it correctly ?

```
weights = [0.4,0.8,1.0]

class_weights = torch.DoubleTensor(weights).cuda()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), the `weight` parameter to `CrossEntropyLoss` should be:

> weight (Tensor, optional) – a manual rescaling weight given to each class. If given, has to be a Tensor of size C.

I assume you have 3 classes `(C=3)`. By the way, are you sure your model is moved to `double()`? Otherwise, you should prefer using `FloatTensor`. For example,

```
nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=torch.FloatTensor([0.4, 0.8, 1.0]))
```

Otherwise, your example looks ok!

Comment: Yes I explicitly moved the model to `double()` , thanks for clarification mate!